# One Process Builder vs Multiple per single Object

Tags: process-builder, bestpractice, architecture

I've read somewhere about an idea of implementing all Process Builders that are executing on a single object within a single Process Builder, instead of using multiple ones (IMO this is a similar approach to what is generally done with triggers).

Is this approach possible to maintain over a longer period of time? Have you seen it used successfully? Also, is it better from a certain technical perspective, for example, is it faster?

Comment: I would be in the camp of one process builder around a process not the entire business logic. In fact, it cannot be done around differing logic as only one branch of the PB can be entered in a given transaction per se. Really though I am in the camp of not using PB as there are too many issue still present that cannot handle anything but the most basic of processes reliably

Comment: From Summer '16 there is an option to either `Stop` or `Evaluate the next criteria` when a PB finishes a specific branch, so it is possible to enter more than one branch in a given transaction. That's the reason I thought that now we could handle more complex logic within a single PB instead of using multiple. And I agree with you, I'm also in a camp of not using PBs at all, but we already have a ton of automation spread out in them, which gets pretty painful when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a great many processes you want to automate, then consolidating them into one flow via `Process Builder` can be a great choice from an *organization* perspective. Doing so will also give you more granular control over *order of execution* within the flow. I'm not certain of any other benefits. Specifically, I doubt it will improve *performance*.

A few words of caution:

- If you have some logic that should be re-evaluated and some that should not, you will at least need to create one flow for each branch.
- You may also need to bifurcate your flows based on if you want the process to start only when a record is created, or also when it is edited.
- There may always be a performance gap between `Process Builder` and a custom built, well optimized `Apex Trigger`. Because of this performance hit, I think you need to consider the case where your flow logic fails.

  - If you had them split out and one flow starts throwing errors, you can simply disable the specific flow that is causing the problem.
  - If you consolidate them, you may find it difficult to extricate or fix the broken logic. This could lead to a longer downtime as you troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian, for your great answer. At this point I believe that leaving them separated could still be a slightly better idea. I'll leave this question open for now to see if somebody else has anything to add. I'll accept an answer in a day or two. Thanks.